# Print contents of PHP file in CTF

Tags: php, ctf

I am working with a PHP vulnerability. Below is the code snippet. Basically, I need to print the contents of `get_flag.php`.

My train of thought is that the following could be the vulnerabilities in the code

1. The `global $secret` variable
2. The `unserialized_safe` function
3. The `hash_equals` built in PHP function

The attack will be somewhere along the line of getting the value of the `global $secret` and then creating a payload in the cookie to exploit the `unserialized_safe` function to print the content of `get_flag.php`. To do that, I have to ensure that I can compute the signature of the payload so that the loop will go into the unserialized portion.

How do I get the value of the `global $secret` in the first place? Or is there something I am missing?

```
<?php
    
    include 'get_flag.php';
    
    class Hacker {
        private $show_flag = FALSE;
        private $username = 'hacker1337';
        
        public function toString() {
            $str = $this->username;
            if($this->show_flag === TRUE) $str .= ' ' . getFlag($this->username); 
            return $str;
        }
    }
    
    function sign($str) {
        global $secret;
        return hash('sha256', $secret . $str);
    }
    
    function unserialize_safe($str) {        
        return unserialize($str, ['allowed_classes' => ['Hacker']]);
    }
    
    if(isset($_COOKIE['hackers']) && isset($_COOKIE['signature'])){
        $serialized_hackers = $_COOKIE['hackers'];
        $signature = $_COOKIE['signature'];
        if (hash_equals(sign($serialized_hackers), $signature) === FALSE) {
            unset($_COOKIE['hackers']);
        } else {
            $serialized_hackers = explode(' ', $serialized_hackers);
            $hackers = array_map('unserialize_safe', $serialized_hackers);
        }        
    }
    
    if(!isset($_COOKIE['hackers']) || !isset($_COOKIE['signature'])) {
        $hackers = [new Hacker];
        $serialized_hackers = implode(' ', array_map('serialize', $hackers));        
        setcookie('hackers', $serialized_hackers);
        setcookie('signature', sign($serialized_hackers));
    }
?>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Secure site 10000</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>The Hacker Wall of Fame:</h1>
<?php foreach($hackers as $hacker): ?>
    <li><?= $hacker->toString() ?></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<p /><a href="?source=1">Show</a>/<a href="/">hide</a> page source<p />
<?php if (isset($_GET['source'])) highlight_file(__FILE__); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you have hash (cookie signature) and salt(cookie hackers). and hashcat (mode 110) allows to get pass(secret) out of ```hash=sha1(pass + salt)```. right?

Comment: @MaximSagaydachny I don't think that's the right path. And what you think is a "salt" isn't.

Comment: Hint: sha256 is vulnerable to length extension attacks.